# LinuxMint 19.1 Tessa does not play sound in the default device

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio

I connected my TV to my laptop using HDMI for a movie and the audio was still playing from the laptop. So, I changed the sound device to the TV and sound got played from TV - All good.

And then, I removed the HDMI cable and started my work. I noticed the 'workspace switch' sound was not heard as well as the logon sound was not heard as well. I played a video but there was no sound.

What's weird is when testing the sound using the 'Test Sound' from the sound settings, sound is working [Front Left and Front Right]. Also the sound while changing the sound volume is also working.

I tried restarting the driver and everything. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself :)

1. Reconnected to the TV. Now the sound output devices shows the HDMI device (TV) and laptop speaker
2. Switched the output device to the laptop speaker.
3. Removed the HDMI device and tried the audio.

All is working normal now.